# How to check that a TField has been modified manually

Tags: delphi

So I'm working on a form that makes use of database grids, I'm having an issue where I need to auto-default a field based upon the amount and GST fields. This will *always* auto-default my field for the user until the point where they manually change my field, at which point it obviously will not do anymore defaulting for that record.

Any ideas on how I can achieve the recognition of a manually modified field in Delphi? Please note I'm not talking about the manual modification of a record so the following code is not applicable to my situation (unless you can somehow find a way to use it).

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate the value in the field when the amount or GST changes, and then calculate whatever the field is you want to *auto-default*. Allow the user to change it, and don't react to that change unless the user modifies the amount or GST again. You can use the [TField.OnChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Data.DB.TField.OnChange) event (on the amount and GST fields) to do so.

Comment: Much appreciated Ken, I didn't think of that.